# JIRA: Find issues linked to issues in other projects dynamically

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jql

Is there a way to find issues linked to issues in other projects without specifying a specific project?  I need to find all issues, from all projects, linked to issues in other projects.

I know that this will find issues in other projects if I can give the issue and project:

```
issue in linkedIssues(XYZ-000) AND project = 'ABC'
```

I need a method that works dynamically so I don't have to specify issue or project.  I don't want the results to return issues that only have links within their own projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [JQL Tricks plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.j-tricks.jql-plugin/server/overview) (*it is not free, but you can use the evaluation*)  then try with:

```
issue in haslinks()
```

From the [official documentation](http://www.j-tricks.com/jqlt-links-functions.html):

> hasLinks([count],[linkType],[query])
>
> Function To find all issues that has links and optionally for a count, link type or matching a query.
>
> Since : v1.0 (Support for query is added in 5.3.10)
>
> Usage/Examples:
>
> issue in hasLinks() - Returns all the issues with atleast one link (inward or outward)

Comment: This will only capture inward/outward links?  For example, it won't catch links between issues in the same project or Epic-Story links?

Comment: It will catch links between issues in the same project. Epic-Story are not links but direct dependencies that can be catched by appending "OR issue in epicsWhereIssueIn("resolution = unresolved")" for example.(you'll need JQL Tricks again) or by simply appending "OR "Epic Link" is not EMPTY" that is just plain JIRA JQL.